# F# environment integration (for scripting)

Tags: .net, powershell, f#, cmd, f#-scripting

I like F# and I want to practice a little by writing some scripts for automation of some annoying task.

How do i interact with other programs the same way i can do from CMD or PowerShell
for example RoboCopy or iisreset or net?

I know i can do it myself with `System.Diagnostics.Process` but it's difficult to do right (return codes, standard streams, etc.) .

There has to be a library for this, any suggestions?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You want to use the [System.Management.Automation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.management.automation%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) namespace.  Here's an example of running some cmdlets from F#.

```
// C:\Program Files (x86)\Reference Assemblies\Microsoft\WindowsPowerShell\3.0
open System.Management.Automation
open System.Management.Automation.Runspaces;

let runSpace = RunspaceFactory.CreateRunspace()
runSpace.Open()
let pipeline = runSpace.CreatePipeline()

let getProcess = new Command("Get-Process")
pipeline.Commands.Add(getProcess)

let sort = new Command("Sort-Object")
sort.Parameters.Add("Property", "VM")
pipeline.Commands.Add(sort)

// Identical to the following PowerShell command line:
// PS > Get-Process | Sort-Object -Property VM | select ProcessName

let output = pipeline.Invoke()
for psObject in output do
    psObject.Properties.Item("ProcessName").Value.ToString()
    |> printfn "%s"
```

You can also build cmdlets with F# and use PowerShell to move data.  Check out [this post](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/fsharpteam/archive/2012/10/03/rethinking-findstr-with-f-and-powershell.aspx) on the Visual Studio F# Team Blog.  It's a good example on how to write a Cmdlet in F#.  You can also [embed F# into PowerShell](http://www.dougfinke.com/blog/index.php/2007/07/27/embedding-f-in-powershell/) but in general it's better to make Cmdlets.

[Cmdlet MSDN reference](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms714395%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)
[Scripting with Windows PowerShell](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/scriptcenter/powershell.aspx)

Comment: no. i don't want to use PowerShell. I want the other way around, to use powerShell stuff, from F#.

Comment: @AK_ I added an example of using cmdlets from F#.

Answer (score 3):

[Fake](http://fsharp.github.io/FAKE/) has an ExecProcess task that might help. Also you could look at the Fake source for more ideas.

Answer (score 2):

If you use the `Developer Command Prompt for VS2012` (available under the Start Menu -> Programs -> Microsoft Visual Studio 2012 -> Visual Studio Tools), you'll have `fsi` (F# Interactive) in the path already. For example:

```
C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 11.0>fsi

Microsoft (R) F# Interactive version 11.0.60315.1
Copyright (c) Microsoft Corporation. All Rights Reserved.

For help type #help;;

> #quit;;

C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 11.0>
```

You can create F# script files -- they use the `*.fsx` file extension -- and then run them using `fsi`. Under Mono on OSX, FreeBSD, and Linux, you can also add a "shebang" to `*.fsx` files and run them just like you would a Python, Perl, etc. script.

EDIT: As far as running the external programs, there are some libraries on NuGet for simplifying this -- [cmd](https://nuget.org/packages/cmd/) is the first one I found. It's for C#, but it should be straightforward to implement some wrapper functions to make it easier to consume from F#.

Comment: yeah. i know. The question was, how can i use for example Robocopy from within F# script

Comment: @AK_ See my edit. I think your best bet is going to be to find something on NuGet -- AFAIK, no one's created an F#-specific library for this. I've used `Process` directly the few times I've had to implement code to run an external process.

Comment: @AK_ I just saw your comment on gradbot's answer -- if you specifically want to call PowerShell cmdlets from F#, you should be able to host a PowerShell process within F# and manipulate/invoke the cmdlets quite easily. IIRC there was an example project for this (in C#) in the PowerShell 2.0 SDK.

Comment: it's not really what i want... but it would be a good start... thanks